# How to dim os x desktop using Cocoa/Core Animation

Tags: cocoa, core-animation

Is there a way to control the brightness of the OS X desktop programmatically using Cocoa or Core Animation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you were actually interested in doing a fade-out or fade-in of the whole screen, [here is a link describing how to do that](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/QuartzDisplayServicesConceptual/Articles/FadeEffects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004232).

The linked document contains examples for how to fade all displays (or a single display) to black (you can change the color), capture the display (where you can display what you'd like), and then fade back. This uses `CGAcquireDisplayFadeReservation()` mentioned in the comment to my other answer.

Is this more like what you were looking for?

Comment: This maybe a better fit of what I was trying to do. Thanks for following through. I'm going to choose this answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 3):

Create a [semi-transparent full-screen view](http://briankc.com/2007/12/15/create-a-transparent-fullscreen-view/) behind your main window.

Comment: Does this answer your question? Or are you looking for any additional help?

Comment: It does, but maybe I should have phrased it differently. I was wondering if I could control the actual screen brightness programmatically instead? Thx

Comment: Do you want to actually control the brightness of the display hardware? If so, I think you're out of luck. However, since you tagged this with core-animation, I'm thinking you maybe want some kind of full-screen visual effect. In which case you can use the CoreGraphics API call CGAcquireDisplayFadeReservation().