# Is there a way to programmatically extend Apple's Expose

Tags: cocoa, core-animation, apple-expose

I'm looking for some pointers on how to reproduce the Apple Expose effect in my own app. Is there an API for Expose? If not how can it be replicated from scratch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no official Exposé API.

What effects are you trying to achieve? [This old Apple Mailing List thread](http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2004/jul/msg00554.html) is on the same topic. The thread includes some [info on how to get a window scaling effect](http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2004/jul/msg00588.html) similar to Exposé. I'm also guessing that your other question about [dimming the desktop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818829/how-to-dim-os-x-desktop-using-cocoa-core-animation) is related. Let us know what else you'd like to do and maybe we can offer some advice.

Comment: Well as stated in the question, I'm trying to reproduce the Expose effect. Specifically I want my app to recognize/discover all open windows and scale them down so they can all be visible at once.

Comment: Sounds good. I just wanted to be clear on what effect you were going for as Exposé uses several different graphical effect depending on which function you invoke. Check out the link I provided in my answer on getting the window scaling effect... it's not a complete solution, but it should get you started. Unfortunately, there is no API that will give you this effect for free.

Comment: Do you know of an unfree API perhaps?